# Why is my adjacency list giving me a ClassCast Exception?

Tags: java, generics, graph

I am creating a graph using an adjacency list. (via an array of linked lists). It fails with a class cast exception when I try to create and array object and cast it back to the original type (The work around for generic arrays).   But when I replace this with a raw type it works. Why is that ?

```
public class Graph {

  int vertices;

  DoublyLinkedList<Integer>[] adjacencyList;

  public Graph(int vertices) {

    this.vertices = vertices;

    // Below line throws an error : Class Cast Exception 
    **adjacencyList = (DoublyLinkedList<Integer>[]) new Object[vertices];** /

    // Replace above line with this line and it works.
    **adjacencyList = new DoublyLinkedList[vertices];**

    for (int i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
      adjacencyList[i] = new DoublyLinkedList<>();
    }
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Graph graph = new Graph(3);
    graph.addEdge(0, 1);
    graph.addEdge(1, 2);
    graph.addEdge(2, 0);
}
```

Comment: Your workaround is not a workaround. It's a bug. An Object[] is not an instance of DoublyLinkedList[], hence the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot for the same reason you cannot do something like

```
Object objArray = new String();
String strArray = ((String)new Object());
```

In other words, every class is an Object, but not all Objects are String.

Comment: Why is the same thing working for me here 

``` public class Stack<V> {

  private int maxSize;
  private int top;
  private V[] arr;
  private int currentSize;

  public Stack(int maxSize) {
    this.maxSize = maxSize;
    arr = (V[]) new Object[maxSize];

  }
}
```

Comment: Because in this case V, without further specification, is equivalent to Object. So if you write public static void main(String[] args) {

    MissingMethod mm = new MissingMethod(5);
    mm.arr[0] = "hello";
  } it will work. But as soon you define, for example, Stack<V extends Integer> the main fails. In general an nice IDE like eclipse will warn you of something like " Unchecked cast from Object[] to V[]"

Answer (score 0):

You are tring to cast `Object` to `DoublyLinkedList<Integer>[]`, but `Object` is not an instance of `DoublyLinkedList<Integer>[]`. Instead you can change

`new Object[vertices];`

to

`new DoublyLinkedList[vertices];`

, but as you can see you will loose your type (you cannot create array of generic classes with types for more information check: [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays)).